# How to attach model functions to model results

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have a Laravel model, and a function in it. How can I attach function to model result when I need? I don't want to use `$appends` because I don't need the function always.

This is my model:

```
class Vendor extends model
    {
        public function status()
        {
           if ($this->active == 1) return 'active';
           else return 'deActive';
        }


}
```

This is my controller that I want code something like this:

```
class VendorController extends Controller
{
    public function info()
    {
        $vendor = Vendor::all();
        $vendor->load('status');
        return $vendor;
    }

    public function infoWithoutStatus()
    {
        $vendor = Vendor::all();
        return $vendor;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mentallurg the controller codes in info() function is an example and it is incorrect; i want the correct code for its implementation

Comment: What is in *info()* incorrect?

Comment: $vendor->load('status');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there isn't any way; because when you declare a function in a model it works with that object; and loads the function result when you call the function or appended function; so for doing this job you should write a foreach for loading the values for each object

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vendor extends model
{
    public function getStatusAttribute()
    {
       if ($this->active == 1) {
           return 'active';
       } 

       return 'deActive';
    }
}
```

Use murators
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation, not just code. Help the OP (and future visitors) to understand _why_ this solves the issue and they might not need to come back again with similar issues.

Comment: it is correct just for object; i wanna to use the code for object array; and it doesn't work for object array

Comment: @nasimjahednia see https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter, i think this will work

Answer (score 0):

you can use appends but don't put it in visible set.

```
class Vendor extends model
{
    protected $appends = ['status'];
    protected $visible = [];

    public function getStatusAttribute()
    {
       return $this->active ? 'active' : 'deActive';
    }
}
```

and in the controller you use it like this:

```
$vendors = Vendor::all();

// without status field
return $vendors;

// with status field
return $vendors->makeVisible('status');
```